# Absolute imports works either in tests or in uvicorn

Tags: python

I have a bit of an odd problem, namely I have this structure:

```
 |-tests
 | |-__init__.py
 | |-domain
 | | |-items
 | | | |-test_service.py
 | |-test_app.py
 |-poetry_demo
 | |-__init__.py
 | |-app.py
 | |-domain
 | | |-__init__.py
 | | |-items
 | | | |-service.py
 | | | |-controller.py
 | | | |-__init__.py
 | | | |-model.py
```

And in `app.py` I do

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from poetry_demo.domain.items.controller import ItemsController
from poetry_demo.domain.items.service import ItemsService

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(ItemsController(service=ItemsService).router, prefix="/items")
```

And when I go into `poetry_demo` dir and run uvicorn with `uvicorn app:app --reload`, I am getting an error:

```
    from poetry_demo.domain.items.controller import ItemsController
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry_demo'
```

But on the same time, when I run `pytest` from the main directory (one above `poetry_demo`), it works perfectly.

To have app running, I need to change `app.py` imports to:

```
from domain.items.controller import ItemsController
from domain.items.service import ItemsService
```

And then it works, but... tests are breaking.

I tried changing import to relative (`.domain...`), but then I am getting

```
    from .domain.items.controller import ItemsController
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've solved the problem. Running *everything* from the top directory helped.

Instead of

```
uvicorn app:app --reload
```

I do

```
uvicorn poetry-demo.app:app --reload
```

I also run tests from there (or from IDE, it also works perfectly).

Maybe this'll help someone :)